# Google Place API- multiple types filter not working

Tags: google-places-api

trying to query google places api to find all nearby places to spent time with friends,but the query returns only 1st type places. Is there any updates for multiple type?
Request looks like smth like this:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=50.7310555,7.0975441&type=bar|cafe|restaurant|night_club&radius=250&key=${myKey}

Comment: If you increase your radius, does this return more results? nearby search should be returning the top 20 or so

Comment: @HarryJ the problem is not in having more result, as I got a lot. I need to have also cafe/restuaurants/night clubs in a resultset. Currently place api return only bars(1st type in my query)